# Is there any repetition in this decision structure?

Tags: python, performance

Is there anyway to simplify this decision structure that I am not seeing? It seems to me that each statement is necessary in determining the correct order. Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
def main():
    again = 'y'
    while again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
        str_1 = input('Enter string 1: ')
        str_2 = input('Enter string 2: ')
        str_3 = input('Enter string 3: ')
        first = min(str_1, str_2, str_3)
        print(first)
        again = input('Another? ')

def min(str1, str2, str3):
    # str1 < str2 < str3
    if str1 < str2 and str2 < str3:
        low = str1

    # str1 < str3 < str2   
    elif str1 < str3 and str3 < str2:
        low = str1

    # str2 < str1 < str3
    elif str2 < str1 and str1 < str3:
        low = str2

    # str2 < str3 < str1
    elif str2 < str3 and str3 < str1:
        low = str2

    # str3 < str1 < str2
    elif str3 < str1 and str1 < str2:
        low = str3

    # str3 < str2 < str1
    elif str3 < str2 and str2 < str1:
        low = str3

    return low

main()
```

Comment: Any reason for not using `min(str1, str2, str3)`?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min

Comment: Your code doesn't take care of the case where all 3 strings are equal (or any 2 strings out of 3 are equal)

Comment: Just practicing to be honest. Started programming recently trying to recognize repetition in my coding.

Comment: Why are you prompting for a string when `input` returns a `int`

Comment: @ChristianCareaga, in python2, `input` _evaluates_ the input string this is very different (and dangerous) to saying it converts to an int. This looks to be Python3 though, so `input` works like `raw_input` from Python2

Comment: ohhi didnt think about it being 3 my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're looking for a minimal tree there are many useless tests... for example

```
if str1 <= str2:
    if str1 <= str3:
        low = str1
    else:
        low = str3
else:
    if str2 <= str3:
        low = str2
    else:
        low = str3
```

i.e. you need just 2 comparison operations to decide what is the minimum (while there are 6 orderings there are only three possible minimum values, that's why two bit of information is enough). In other words if you know that an element is smaller than both the others you don't care what is the relative order between those other two.

Even in your form there are less cases needed:

```
if str1 <= str2 and str1 <= str3:
    low = str1
elif str2 <= str1 and str2 <= str3:
    low = str2
else:
    low = str3
```

The typical form used (that scales better as you increase the number of elements) is however:

```
low = x1
if x2 < low: low = x2
if x3 < low: low = x3
...
if xN < low: low = xN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 low=str1

if str2 < low
    low = str2
elif str3 < low 
    low = str3
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already a built-in function called [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)

```
def main():
    again = 'y'
    while again.lower() == 'y':
        str_1 = input('Enter string 1: ')
        str_2 = input('Enter string 2: ')
        str_3 = input('Enter string 3: ')
        first = min(str_1, str_2, str_3)
        print(first)
        again = input('Another? ')
```

When run:

```
Enter string 1: 5
Enter string 2: 8
Enter string 3: 3
3
Another? N
```

---

Since you've clarified this is practice, there is another way in doing so:

```
if str1 < str2 and str2 < str3:
    low = str1
```

Can be:

```
if str1 < str2 < str3:
    low = str1
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Answer (score 0):

There is a builtin function `min()` that already does this better than yours. So to answer your question - *yes, you can simplify it a lot!*

```
def main():
    while True:
        strs = [input('Enter string {}: ').format(i) for i in range(1,4)]
        print(min(strs))    # first
        if input('Another? ') in "yY":
            break
```